# Corona SDK Screen Transition Not Working

Tags: ios, lua, sdk, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I need to have my game transition from one scene to another in the storyboard api when the button pbtn is pressed. Here is my code.

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

--Forward References

local title

local centerX = display.contentCenterX
local centerY = display.contentCenterY
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

function anim_pbtn(event)
        transition.to(pbtn, {time = 500, alpha = 0, xScale = 2, yScale = .6})
        storyboard.gotoScene("game", "fade", 1000)
end

function scene:createScene(event)
    local screenGroup = self.view

    mbg = display.newImage("mbg.png")
        mbg.x = centerX
        mbg.y = centerY
        mbg.width = display.width
        mbg.height = display.height

    title = display.newImage("title.png")
        title.xScale = .7
        title.yScale = .7
        title.x = centerX

    pbtn = display.newImage("play_btn.png")
        pbtn.xScale = .7
        pbtn.yScale = .7
        pbtn.x = centerX
        pbtn.y = display.contentHeight - 210

    ibtn = display.newImage("ins_btn.png")
        ibtn.xScale = .7
        ibtn.yScale = .7
        ibtn.x = centerX
        ibtn.y = display.contentHeight - 130

    cbtn = display.newImage("cre_btn.png")
        cbtn.xScale = .7
        cbtn.yScale = .7
        cbtn.x = centerX
        cbtn.y = display.contentHeight - 50
end

function scene:enterScene(event)
    pbtn:addEventListener("tap", anim_pbtn)
end

function scene:exitScene(event)

end

function scene:destroyScene(event)

end



scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene
```

I just needed to add this to the screenGroup for the transition to take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added all of my images to my group called screenGroup and everything worked fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 'game.lua' file in the same folder as this file ?
When you call gotoscene('blabla') it will look for 'blabla.lua' in the current directory :)

I copied / pasted your code to test it here and it worked for me (with a game.lua file).

Comment: I do have a game.lua file. I will try it again and get back to you.

Comment: This still did not work even with a game.lua file. Could the problem be in my game.lua file:

Comment: Here is my game.lua code: local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

--Forward References

local title

local centerX = display.contentCenterX
local centerY = display.contentCenterY
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

function scene:createScene(event)
    local screenGroup = self.view
end

function scene:enterScene(event)
end

function scene:exitScene(event)

end

function scene:destroyScene(event)

end

Comment: scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene

Comment: All works for me, it transitions correctly. Do you see your icons correctly on first scene ? What error do you get ?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is then ? The second scene loads correctly, try replacing the enterScene handler by that in game.lua: function scene:enterScene(event) print 'enterScene in game.lua' end

Comment: You should see the message in the terminal after clicking your button / icon :)

Comment: Ok. I tested this with the print command in the game.lua file. The buttons will not dissapear without me putting buttonName:removeSelf() in the exit scene function. Also, the transition does not show up. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Nevermind I found the problem. I had to add everything to my screenGroup group.